# Spyder IPython Console restarts itself after running part of code

Tags: python, lidar

I have a piece of code for which I've installed the necessary packages. I have a problem after running this 2 lines of code:

```
data_all = spatial.readLidarPoints(inFile)
data_g = spatial.readLidarPoints(inFile,classification=lidarprocessor.CLASSIFICATION_GROUND)
```

The IPython Console just restarts after running those lines and I get thrown back to console line [1]. I use conda on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

I'll attach the full code:

```
import pylidar
from pylidar import lidarprocessor
from pylidar.toolbox import spatial
from pylidar.toolbox import interpolation

from functools import partial
import pyproj
import numpy as np

import gbdxtools
from gbdxtools.task import env
from gbdxtools import CatalogImage

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#from rasterio import features
import numpy.ma 

from skimage import morphology
from gbdxtools.vectors import Vectors

import matplotlib.patches as Patches
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection

from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from shapely import ops
from shapely.geometry import shape

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

from matplotlib import cm

import os
#import wget




inp = pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:32136') # 32136
outp = pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:4326')
tfm = partial(pyproj.transform, inp, outp)

BINSIZE = 1

def foot_to_meter(x):
    return x*0.3048 # check resolution


def sp_to_wgs84(p):
    xin, yin, zin = p
    xout, yout = tfm(foot_to_meter(xin), foot_to_meter(yin))
    return [xout, yout, foot_to_meter(zin)]


exists = os.path.isfile('tn_clean.las') 
if exists:
    inFile='tn_clean.las'
else:
    inFile=wget.download('https://s3.amazonaws.com/notebooks-demo-data/tn_clean.las')


#(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
data_all = spatial.readLidarPoints(inFile)
data_g = spatial.readLidarPoints(inFile,classification=lidarprocessor.CLASSIFICATION_GROUND)
```

Comment: Are you running this in a conda environment?

Comment: Yes @Borealis I'm running it in a conda environment, all is installed on a VM with Ubuntu 18.04